# Find Docking a Window to Left/Right Side

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there any way to find out an EVENT (or property or method or something like) for detect Window Docking to Left or Right Side?

**Description:**

- With WindowState property you can find out, when you windows changed state between these three states Normal / Minimized / Maximized. After Windows 7, you can have two kind of docking "Dock To Left" and "Dock To Right". I can't find any property or event in Window Class.
- You Can dock a Window to left with **WinKey + Left** or dock a Window to right with **WinKey + Right**.

**Question:**

I need to have some changes in my window after docking to left or right. I need one trigger in WPF/XAML but i can't find any property or event related to Docking to left/right.

Comment: The real question is what do you want that for....

Comment: I need to turn off my customizable shadow (around of window) when the window is docked to left/right like as Maximized state.

Answer (score 2):

In the SizeChanged event you can detect if the window is docked with:

```
bool isDocked = 
     window.WindowState == WindowState.Normal &&
     window.Width != window.RestoreBounds.Width &&
     window.Height != window.RestoreBounds.Height
```

at least, this is a pretty good indicator.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any special event because 'docking' to left/right is not a special operation like minimize/maximize, merely a particular way of repositioning of the window. The user can mimic 'docking' exactly by restoring, moving and resizing the window. Therefore, your UI logic appears questionable. Imagine the user restoring the window and then resizing it so that it fills approximately half a screen close to the right edge of the screen. What should happen?

Protip: there may be multiple monitors and your window may straddle them.

Comment: I have a shadow around of window like most of windows (google chrome, Visual Studio and more) and it's self-implemented. When the window is maximized then, i have trigger to turn-off shadow. When the window is docking to left/right side, this shadow is visible and make distance from edge of monitor and this is awful. This shadow is a kind of custom implemented shadow on a WPF Window. The Window is 'WindowStyle=None' and `AllowsTransparency=None`and None `WindowChrome.WindowChrome`. The shadow is built with a border with a customizable width/height of shadow.

Comment: I see. You will probably have to detect the 'docked' condition in a `SizeChanged` event handler (or in `OnSizeChanged`) and turn off the shadow from there — or, better, set a dependency property and bind the border's width to that. Then you can set this same dependency property from `StateChanged` (maximize/minimize/restore) too for consistency.

Comment: Unfortunately, docking to the left/right side of the screen IS a special operation.  The native desktop manager still saves the 'restore' position of the screen.  I have run into a need for this same event because I want to save my window position (including maximized state) when the program closes and restore that position when the program launches.  When the window is docked, there is no 'restore' position to be saved because the window state is 'normal'.

Comment: `The user can mimic 'docking' exactly` that's actually not true. Windows remembers the old window size. When the user drags the window off the edge, the old window size is restored. So there's additional state involved.

Answer (score 0):

I did this around my window in it's Template:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="5" Margin="-5"
        Effect="{DynamicResource ShadowEffect}">
  <...>
</Border>
```

Negative margin negates border thickness.